# Can someone explain for me what the different with or without co npm?

Tags: javascript

i'm learning to use generator function but i dont see the different without it?

```
var co = require('co');
var axios = require('axios');
var urls = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/5'
];
```

with co and generator function

```
co(function*(){
  yield urls.map(data =>
      axios.get(data)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
)})
```

without it

```
urls.map(link =>
    axios.get(link)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
)
```

i still got the same data

Comment: This is a good question, but it's too broad for stack overflow. Read up on coroutines, asynchronous generator functions, `map` vs `forEach`, Promises, and async/await.

Comment: Don't use "coroutines" these days. Just start learning `async`/`await` (presuming you already mastered promises).

Answer (score 0):

A generator is a function that can stop midway and then continue from where it stopped. In other words, a generator appears to be a function but it behaves like an iterator.
In a normal call of the code like yours, no difference should be expected.